# How to toggle line coverage in Xcode

Tags: xcode, code-coverage

I don't know how to turn on and off the side bar which shows code coverage in a given file.

I've googled a bunch of terms but they all turn up how to enable code coverage in the scheme. I am specifically referring to the coverage the shows up in the code inspector like such:

[image]

If you know how to toggle this on/off please advise. Bonus points if you can tell me the name of this column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Editor > Show Code Coverage`

Note though that this is ***not*** a per-file setting.

Also, there is a setting for toggling iteration counts in `Preferences > Text Editing > Editing` (if you only want red/green status indicators)

Now, regarding the bonus part, it seems that there is no reference for this 'column' so I guess the best chance is to either ask the folks at Apple in the dev forums or crawl through [wwdc transcriptions](http://asciiwwdc.com) hoping to find a reference on some demo of the feature.